# ¿Que supone poner & delante de un struct?

Tags: c, punteros, struct

estaba haciendo unos ejercicios cuando he visto lo siguiente:
Tengo esta función:

```
bool film_equals(tFilm* film1, tFilm* film2);
```

Y cuando he querido usarla, no la necesitaba con punteros, por lo que sería algo así :

```
if( film_equals(&film,&temporal->e.film)==true)
 {
   isFavorited=true;
 }
```

Siendo `tFilm film` un parametro de la función y `temporal->e.film` un nodo cuyo valor es la película

Mi pregunta aquí es.. ¿por qué falla si no le pongo & delante de los parámetros? ¿Qué supone esto exactamente para mis valores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Y cuando he querido usarla, no la necesitaba con punteros.

Entonces, no deberías usar punteros:

```
bool film_equals(tFilm* film1, tFilm* film2);
//               ~~~~~^        ~~~~~^
//                  \              \___ Puntero a 'tFilm'
//                   \___ Puntero a 'tFilm'
```

Si en lugar de punteros, quieres instancias, omite el asterisco (`*`):

```
bool film_equals(tFilm film1, tFilm film2);
//               ~~~~~        ~~~~~
//                  \            \___ Instancia de 'tFilm'
//                   \___ Instancia de 'tFilm'
```

> ¿por qué falla si no le pongo & delante de los parámetros?

El [operador et](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) obtiene un puntero a una instancia. Así que si tienes un objeto de tipo `tFilm` llamado `film`, al aplicarle el operador et: `&film` obtienes un puntero a `tFilm` (`tFilm*`) que es exactamente lo que te pide tu función `film_ecuals` y por lo que falla en caso de no proveer unos argumentos que coincidan con la firma de la función.

Answer (score 1):

Imaginemos que nuestra estructura `tFilm` fue declarado de esta manera:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int price;
    int film;
}tFilm;
```

Luego, vamos a suponer que los [offset](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(inform%C3%A1tica)) de cada miembro de la estructura `tFilm` son los siguientes:

```
typedef struct 
{
    int price; //offset 0
    int film;//offset 4
}tFilm;
```

El [offset](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(inform%C3%A1tica)) lo único que indica, es el desplazamiento necesario para poder sumarlo con la dirección base (la del primer miembro) de la estructura y de este modo, obtener la dirección de memoria de algún miembro de la estructura `tFilm`.

Listo, teniendo esta información, podremos entender fácilmente la siguiente pregunta:

> > ¿Que supone poner & delante de un struct?

Para responder a la pregunta, plantearé el siguiente código:

```
bool film_equals(tFilm* f1, tFilm* f2)
{
    return (f1->film == f2->film);
}

int main(void)
{
    tFilm film1 = {2, 23}; //Se crea la primera estructura en memoria
    tFilm film2 = {3, 26};//Se crea la segunda estructura en memoria
    if(film_equals(&film1, &film2))
        printf("Equals!");
    else 
        printf("No-equals!");
    return 0;
}
```

En el ejemplo de arriba, definimos dos punteros implícitos (`film1` y `film2`) e inicializamos la estructura con valores por defecto.

Adicionalmente, asumiremos las direcciones de memoria de las dos estructuras que hemos creado en memoria:

```
-> 1. film1
int price; -> Address: 0x4
int film; -> Address: 0x8

-> 1. film2
int price; -> Address: 0x24
int film; -> Address: 0x28
```

Al momento que esta función se invoque:

```
film_equals(&film1, &film2)
```

**¿Qué estaríamos pasando?**

Básicamente lo que estamos pasando es la dirección base de la estructura `tFilm`.

Y esto se debe, porqué el código de arriba, en realidad se convierte a esto:

```
film_equals(&film1.price, &film2.price)
```

Para que posteriormente, el compilador lo interprete de esta forma (esta es la manera como se lo leería a bajo nivel):

```
film_equals(film1 + 0, film2 + 0)
```

Si te das cuenta, el miembro `price` en realidad es reemplazado por su respectivo `offset` (obviamente, esto es calculado por el mismo compilador).

Entonces, si sabemos que el puntero implícito `film1` tiene la dirección base (en este caso es `0x4`) de la estructura `tFilm`, con tal solo sumar un `0` a dicha dirección, obtendría la dirección de memoria del primer miembro y esto aplica también para el puntero implícito `film2`.

Entonces, esto quiere decir que el primer parámetro de la función `film_equals` tendrá guardado la dirección `0x4` (que corresponde al bloque de memoria que apunta `film1`).

Lo mismo pasaría con el segundo parámetro, se le estaría pasando la dirección `0x24` (porqué corresponde a la dirección del primer miembro al que apunta `film2`).

Ahora entendiendo esto, podemos concluir que si nosotros llegáramos a quitar el ampersand `&` en la siguiente llamada:

```
film_equals(film1, film2)
```

Lo que estaríamos pasando, es el contenido del primer miembro de la estructura `tFilm`. Básicamente el código equivalente sería de esta forma:

```
film_equals(film1.price, film2.price)
```

Que a su vez, el compilador lo interpreta de esta forma:

```
//Acuérdate, el offset del miembro price dijimos que iba a ser 0.
film_equals(*(film1 + 0), *(film2 + 0))
```

Entonces, nos damos cuenta, lo que estamos pasando en este caso, es el contenido que tenga ambas direcciones de memoria (`0x4` corresponde al primer miembro del bloque1 al que apuntaba `film1` y `0x24` al bloque2 que apuntaba `film2`).

Y si revisamos nuestra tabla que habíamos colocado anteriormente, nos afirma lo que recibiría el primer parámetro de la función `film_equals` que sería un `2` (este era el valor que tenía el miembro `price` del primer bloque de memoria al que apuntaba `film1`) y el segundo parámetro recibiría un `3` (este era el valor que tenía el miembro `price` del segundo bloque de memoria al que apuntaba `film2`).

Sin embargo, esto es peligroso, porqué las direcciones `0x2` y `0x3` las recibe los punteros de la función, pero luego la rutina accedería a esas direcciones que ni sabemos si al programa le pertenecen o no, es decir, la aplicación dejaría de funcionar, porqué el sistema operativo no dejará que accedas a una dirección en la cual no se tiene acceso.

**POR ESA RAZÓN** es **NECESARIO** anteponer el ampersand `&` a los punteros `film1` y `film2`, de lo contrario ocurriría un [fallo de segmentación](https://es.quora.com/Por-qu%C3%A9-me-da-error-de-fallo-de-segmentaci%C3%B3n-al-ejecutar-mi-c%C3%B3digo).

Ahora, sigamos con la siguiente duda:

> > Siendo tFilm film un parámetro de la función y temporal->e.film un nodo cuyo valor es la película

Esto solo podría pasar, si nuestra función fuera definida de esta forma:

```
bool film_equals(tFilm f1, tFilm f2)
```

Al momento de llamar a la función:

```
film_equals(film1, film2)
```

No ocurriría ningún error de ejecución en el programa, es más, todo estaría a salvo.

Sin embargo, ...

**¿Por qué no ocurrió un fallo de segmentación?**

La respuesta es sencilla. No se está pasando la dirección base que tenga guardada el puntero implicito `film1`, sino, se estaría reservando memoria para una nueva estructura de tipo `tFilm`, es decir, el contenido que tenía el anterior bloque de memoria, se lo copia al nuevo bloque de memoria. Entonces, podemos concluir que tanto el primer y segundo parámetro, lo que recibe es la dirección base del nuevo bloque de memoria que se haya reservado y a esto se lo conoce como paso por valor y como sabrás, si repetimos este proceso muchas veces, será lento y esto se debe por la creación de un nuevo objeto (bloque o región de memoria) y sobretodo, por la copia de datos que se deberá de mandar al nuevo objeto al que apuntará el primer o segundo parámetro de la función `film_equals`.

**Recomendación:** Siempre usa el paso por referencia en estos casos, así envías directamente la dirección de memoria, sin embargo, debes tener cuidado en no olvidarte de anteponer el ampersand (`&`).

Me pareció muy interesante tu duda. Espero que te sirva mi explicación.

Answer (score 0):

Al estar declarada con asteriscos `bool film_equals(tFilm* film1, tFilm* film2);` quiere decir que recibe `apuntadores`: direcciones de memoria a `tFilm*`. Con el `&` obtienes la dirección de memoria de `film` y de `temporal->e.film`. Si le quitas el `&` no estas pasando direcciones de memoria (`apuntadores`), sino valores y esa es la razón de que truene.